# Phonegap Angular2 with typescript issue with loading files when building app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

I have issue with building application with angular 2 and phonegap. On lite-server works great, but when i compile to phonegap, app is stucked on loading. When i opened file in browser that are in `platforms/android/assets/www/index.html` i get `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` when i set base href to it using window.location i get CORS error.

I have tried different ways but still don't understand how to build it? Please can somebody provide an explanation how to build app with angular 2 that will be inside app?